# character U+ffffffc2 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]

Tags: python, teradata

I'm extracting some data from Teradata and got the interesting error;

```
    return '' if v is None else str(v)
ValueError: character U+ffffffc2 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

Here is how I got it:

```
def none_to_blank(v):
    return '' if v is None else str(v)

cur.execute(sql_extract.format(...))

for r in cur:
    a = [none_to_blank(x) for x in r]
    # More lines...
```

As I searched a bit, I found that `ffffffc2` is `4294967234`

I don't have the permissions to make a change on the data source and I can't skip a row/line/data

Is there anyway to convert and use this weird character?

Comment: It looks that something/someone has realized a sign extension. But what is v? I cannot guess what object can build a character of code .0xffffffc2 in `str` function.

Comment: @SergeBallesta v is the parameter I'm passing with none_to_blank(x) . it's the data in the given column

Comment: The range `U+0000` to `U+10fffff` represents [all possible Unicode code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).  If `v` is a `bytearray` you can try a different encoding as in `v.decode('cp1252')`.  Or you can do `v.decode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass')` and the bad characters will show as undecoded bytes in the resulting string.  Change `surrogatepass` to `replace` and they become question marks and change to `ignore` and they disappear.  Both are irresponsible.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I'm not sure about the character set of `v` at this point but it's worth a try.

Comment: I see this same issue [being asked about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162318/need-to-skip-line-containing-value-error) in 2016 with no real answer.  In April of 2018, someone [had a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024626/sqlalchemy-unicode-error-querying-teradata-database) and solved the problem by going with an older ODBC driver.  [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236025/valueerror-character-u590048-is-not-in-range-u0000-u10ffff-mac-os) from this year also implicates ODBC.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Replacing the ODBC driver is a long shot for me. But I'm assessing the `encode` option now.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski can you write your solution as an answer so that I can accept it.